# Como fazer contornar uma acentuação no mysql + Php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-select, acentuação

Tenho na minha base de dados palavras com acentos e quando quero chamar eu uso esse SQL abaixo.

Mas caso uma palavra no banco de dados tenha acento eu preciso também usar a palavra acentuada na minha pesquisa, caso contrário, não retorna nada.

Como eu faço para contornar essa a situação e pesquisar tanto palavras acentuadas como não acentuadas?

```
 SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE status_pr='online' AND (LCASE(nome_pr) LIKE '%$get%' 
 OR LCASE(descricao_pr) LIKE '%$get%' OR LCASE(marca_pr) LIKE '%$get%'
 OR LCASE(linha_pr) LIKE '%$get%' OR LCASE(categoria_pr) LIKE '%$get%')
```

No código acima, **$get** é a variável PHP com aquilo que será buscado.

Comment: Qual charset e collate está sendo usado? `utf8`, exceto pelo collate `utf8_bin`, ignora acentuação no LIKE.

Comment: cherset é utf8_bin o collate não estou usando

Comment: utf8_bin é o collate.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Copiando</strike> Baseado nessa [resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304464/mysql-diacritic-insensitive-search-spanish-accents/3304596#3304596), você só tem que selecionar os campos usando utf8 como charset:

```
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE status_pr='online' AND (LCASE(nome_pr) LIKE _utf8'%$get%' 
 OR LCASE(descricao_pr) LIKE _utf8'%$get%' OR LCASE(marca_pr) LIKE _utf8'%$get%'
 OR LCASE(linha_pr) LIKE _utf8'%$get%' OR LCASE(categoria_pr) LIKE _utf8'%$get%')
```

Comment: Excelente dica, me ajudou muito, obrigado @Thomas.

Answer (score 3):

Tente fazer assim:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `produtos`
  WHERE status_pr='online' AND nome_pr LIKE _utf8 'SAO PAULO' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

mais informação -> http://www.dicas-l.com.br/arquivo/consultas_case-insensitive_no_postgresql_e_no_mysql.php#.VI7iiyvF_AY

Comment: Só lembrando que o COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci já faz a comparação ser **c**ase **i**nsensitive, fazendo a função `LCASE` ser desnecessária para o caso.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304464/mysql-diacritic-insensitive-search-spanish-accents/3304596#3304596

Baseado nessa pergunta encontrei uma resposta que fala sobre o
`SELECT CONVERT(column_name USING utf8) FROM table_name LIKE '%giga%'`
que resolveu o meu problema, isso pode ajudar outros. Obrigado Thomas